# Internet Traffic counter and current speed for my laptop with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, internet, internet-connection, internet-speed

I'm looking for a free software that shows me total traffic during the last connection to the Internet and the current speed.

I don't care about what program connects to the Internet. I want to know the current speed, total bytes downloaded and uploaded. That's it.

Is there any way to see it in Windows 7 without any additional software?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of, here is a free program, that shows you total traffic:
Network Meter Version 9.6
http://addgadgets.com/network_meter/

Secondly you could use "Task Manager" or "Resource Monitor" to see current speed. Both tools are part of windows. Click start and write either in the search field of your start menu to find them.

Finally to see total traffic look at the properties for your network connection. You can find this in the control panel: "Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections" or you can right-click the network icon in system tray (next to the clock) and open "Network and Sharing Center" in the windows that open, look for blue text after the word: "Connections:"
The reason I write "blue text" is that it is not called the same in all computers, on mine it's called "Ethernet2".

Answer (score 1):

**Download and Upload size :**

Right click on your *network connection* and select *Status*

---

**Network traffic and speed :**

You can use **Resource Monitor** tools that you can find it in:

> Start > Run > resmon

press Enter!

---

**Full Control :**

For a full control on your intenet download and upload and speed use this perfect 1.5 MegaByte size tool(it's free) :

**Download link :** http://dl.downloadha.com/Kave/up/NetWorx_5.1.7(www.Downloadha.com).zip

**Password :** `www.downloadha.com`